# How do timers work in pygame?

Tags: python, time, pygame

I'm trying to get my game to pick a number between 1 and 6 every 2 seconds. How would I do this?

I have the `random.randrange(1,6)` and `pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 1000)` but I don't know how to connect them in any way. So far it just generates random numbers every tick.

Can I have some suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of code that you can share, even if it is not behaving the way you would like it to?

Comment: Or even this one could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056444/pygame-time-set-timer-confusion

Answer (score 0):

You listen for the event in your event loop, similar to this answer: [How can I detect if the user has double-clicked in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918808/how-can-i-detect-if-the-user-has-double-clicked-in-pygame)

Also 1000 is one second.  You can cancel the event by using zero: `pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 0)`